# How to remove the space from the end of a string displayed with Graphics in Java?

Tags: java, swing, graphics

My class `GraphicButton.java` creates a custom `JButton` with a certain text and font and a rectangular border. My problem is that there is some extra space between the last character in the string and the end of the border that I would like to remove.

Here is what an instance of a `GraphicButton` looks like with the string "PLAY" and the font [FFF Forward](http://dl.1001fonts.com/fff-forward.zip)  (*Direct Download Link*) added to a `JFrame`. **The red line is the space I would like to remove**.

[image]

Here is the code I'm using (`JFrame` creation and setup omitted):

`GraphicButton.java`**:**

```
public class GraphicButton extends JButton {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   //Fields
   private String text;
   private Font font;

   //Constructor
   public GraphicButton(String text, Font font) {
       super(text);

       this.text = text;
       this.font = font;
       //Setting preferred size here.
       this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(this.getFontMetrics(font).stringWidth(text), this.getFontMetrics(font).getAscent()));
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
       g.setFont(this.font);

       //Draw text
       g.drawString(this.text, 0, this.getHeight());
       //Draw border
       g.drawRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
   }
}
```

I'm running Eclipse on a Mac with Java 1.8.

Comment: That space is the space between letters.  I guess you can draw "PLAY" on a BufferedImage, find the rightmost space, remove the space, and pass the modified BufferedImage as an ImageIcon to the JButton.

Comment: I like your suggestion @GilbertLeBlanc, it's just that I don't know how to do what you are suggesting. Please add something to your answer to show me what to do.

Comment: Read my article, [Java Swing Marquee](http://java-articles.info/articles/?p=681), to see how I manipulate a BufferedImage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might be able to use the `TextLayout` to get a better width calculation.

In the example below you can see the different between using the `TextLayout` and `FontMetrics`:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.font.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;

public class DrawTest extends JPanel
{
    String text;

    public DrawTest(String text)
    {
        this.text = text;
//      setFont( new Font("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 24) );
        setFont( new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 24) );
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.setFont( getFont() );
        g2d.setPaint(Color.RED);

        //  Draw text using FontMetrics

        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();
        Rectangle2D rect = fm.getStringBounds(text, g2d);
        rect.setRect(rect.getX() + 100, rect.getY() + 50, rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight());
        g2d.draw(rect);

        //  Draw text using TextLayout

        g2d.setPaint(Color.BLACK);

        Point2D loc = new Point2D.Float(100, 50);
        FontRenderContext frc = g2d.getFontRenderContext();
        TextLayout layout = new TextLayout(text, getFont(), frc);
        layout.draw(g2d, (float)loc.getX(), (float)loc.getY());

        Rectangle2D bounds = layout.getBounds();
        bounds.setRect(bounds.getX()+loc.getX(), bounds.getY()+loc.getY(), bounds.getWidth(), bounds.getHeight());
        g2d.draw(bounds);
    }

    private static void createAndShowUI()
    {
        DrawTest text = new DrawTest("This is some ugly test i");

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add( text );
        frame.setSize(400, 200);
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Also you should NOT:

1. be setting the preferred size. Instead you should override the `getPreferredSize()` method to return the size
2. set the font in the painting method. All components support a setFont() method. So just set the Font in the constructor.

Comment: To get your method to work, I had to call `Math.ceil()` on `bounds.getX()` and `bounds.getY()` because they were negative and `Math.floor()` on `bounds.getWidth()` and `bounds.getHeight()` because they were greater than the actual width and height. I also changed `Point2D loc` to `new Point2D.float(0, getHeight())` to put the text in the correct spot.

Comment: @TurtulWarrior, glad the suggestion helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: I will accept your answer, but I noticed that you didn't add any calls to `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()` to your answer. Was it just me that needed them to be called or could this be a problem for other users in the future?

Comment: @MasterBlaster, Rarely will the code ever be 100% what you need, since we are not here to write the code for you only point you in the right direction to solve your problem. There is no need to change the code posted here as it works correctly. That is it demonstrates the different values return by the two approaches by painting rectangles. How would this code draw a rectangle correctly if some of the values are negative? I have no idea why your values are negative.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you for all your help.